# Object doesn't support property or method atob

Tags: angularjs, html, google-visualization, internet-explorer-9

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  </script>
```

I have loader.js in my libraries folder for google charts but I get the error:"Object doesn't support property or method atob" in IE9. I have done crtF on 'atob' and I could only find it in the loader.js which looks like Z.global.atob.

How can you use google charts in IE9?

Comment: `atob` does base64 encoding. It's not supported in IE9. You can add a polyfill for it.

Comment: Here is the answer about whether it works on IE9: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1586

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi According to the issue ticket I've posted above people say it works on IE9 but not in IE8.

Comment: I added a polyfill and it worked thanks @SzabolcsDézsi

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message, the `loader.js` script requires the [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) function to be present on the global object (`window` in browsers).

It was added in IE10 so with IE9 it is not found.

You can work around the issue by adding a polyfill for `atob` and `btoa`.

I tried this one and worked like a charm for me:

https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js